# OpenBSD Error Code 1 After Restarting Server

Tags: server, ssh

This is what errors are coming up when checking status of the service.
[image]

When I go to check the debug logs this is what I see [image]

I tried running `ssh-keygen -A` but it did not do anything.

Comment: OpenBSD is not supported by AskUbuntu.

Comment: @waltinator perhaps the OP is referring to "OpenBSD Secure Shell Server" rather than OpenBSD as the OS? (I don't think BSD uses systemd does it?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to carefully check the permissions of the mentioned files and make them equal to shown below:

> ```
> $ ls -al /etc/ssh/*
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 553122 Mar  4  2019 /etc/ssh/moduli
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   1580 Mar  4  2019 /etc/ssh/ssh_config
> -rw------- 1 root root    668 Mar 11  2015 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    608 Mar 11  2015 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
> -rw------- 1 root root    227 Mar 11  2015 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    180 Mar 11  2015 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
> -rw------- 1 root root    411 Dec  6  2020 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    100 Dec  6  2020 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
> -rw------- 1 root root   1675 Mar 11  2015 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    400 Mar 11  2015 /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    338 Dec  6  2020 /etc/ssh/ssh_import_id
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   3264 Mar  4  2019 /etc/ssh/sshd_config
> ```

Then restart SSH daemon by

```
sudo service sshd restart
```